# How do I prove that if x is odd then x^16 is odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know how to show $x^2$ is odd but unsure about x^16

Also assuming an odd number = 2k+1

Comment: $x^{16} = (((x^2)^2)^2)^2$

Comment: It might be easier to prove *all* $x^k$ are odd.  But Kaynex comment is good.

Comment: Or prove that if $y^2$ is even then $y$ is even. Then apply $4$ times for a contradiction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just apply your proof four times.
For example $x^2$ is odd gives $(x^2)^2=x^4$ is odd... and so on and so forth

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work with $x^17$, although the proof of it is as simple.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on how you show it four times.

Comment: 1 time: $x$ is odd so $x^2$ is odd. Two times: $x^2$ is odd so $x^4 = (x^2)^2$ is odd.  Three times $x^4$ is odd so $x^8 = (x^4)^2$ is odd.  Four times: $x^8$ is odd so $x^{16} = (x^8)^2$ is odd.

Comment: @fleablood but do I have to plug in 2k+1 each time? Because isn't if very hard to calculate (2k+1) ^16?

Comment: Nevermind I got it

Comment: No.  You do not. You said you have already proven if $x$ is odd then $x^2$ is odd.  So plug in $x^2$.  That *IS* an odd number isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I can't help but point out if $a$ is odd then $a^k$ is odd for *ALL* $k \in N$ (and if $a$ is even $a^k$ is even for all $k \in N$.

Seems like you might as well prove them for all as you'll just be asked later.

Pf: An odd number times an odd number is odd because $(2n +1)(2m+1) = 4n + 2(n+m) + 1$ is odd and an even number times an even number is even because $2n*2m = 4nm$ is even.

So by induction $a^1=a$ is odd|even.

If $a^k$ is odd|even then $a^{k+1} = a^k*a$ is odd|even.

So by inducition for any $k \in N$, then $a^k$ is even|odd $\iff$ $a$ is even|odd

Answer (score 0):

Try to write $x$ as a product of prime factors.

You should have: $x=a_1^{b1}a_2^{b_2}...a_n^{b_n}$, where $\forall i\in \Bbb N, a_i$ is prime. Then just put it to the 16-th power.

Comment: I kind of like this as a theoretical reason.  Might be subtle for a novice though.

Comment: @fleablood Right, but if you write it with actual numbers, I think it becomes really understandable. Like, $12=2^2*3$, or $13=13^1$. Even with bigger numbers, I think it stays readable.

Comment: Yeah, I like this answer.  If $x$ is odd then $x = a_1^{b_1}....$ have no 2 as factors.  Neither does $x^{16} = a_1^{16b_1}...$ so $x^{16}$ is odd too.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you have a few typos.  You want "where $\forall b_i \in \mathbb N$, $a_i$ is prime."

Comment: @fleablood That's the spirit, but I don't want to say too much... I think it's better for the OP to come to the solution by themselves ;)

Comment: @fleablood Edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can prove all $x^n$ is odd if $x$ is odd.

$x^1$ is odd.  Assuming $x^n$ is odd we can show $x^{n+1}$ is odd be the following $x^{n+1} \mod 2 \equiv (x^n \mod 2)(x^1 \mod 2) \mod 2 \equiv 1 \cdot1 \mod 2 \equiv 1 $ so by induction it is true for all $x^n$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is   odd,
then $x-1$ is even.

Therefore
$x^n-1
=(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
$
is even
(since $x-1$ is even).

Therefore
$x^n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

The power of 2 in the prime decomposition of x is 0. The power of 2 in the prime decomposition of x^n is 0*n=0.

Answer (score -1):

If $x=2y+1$ then
$$
x^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}2^iy^i=2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}2^{i-1}y^i\right)+1,
$$
which is odd.

Comment: Why the downvote?